# $G$ is an open subset of $ \mathbb R$ such that $ 0 \notin G $ $ \implies$ {$xy | x , y \in G$ } is open?

Tags: real-analysis

If $G$ is an open subset of $ \mathbb R$ such that $ 0 \notin G $ , then is it true that $H:=\{ xy \mid x , y \in G \}$ is an open subset of $ \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

There's no need for anything fancy here; you can go straight to the definition.

Let $x,y\in G$, and consider $xy$.  Because $G$ is open, you can find some $\epsilon$ so that $(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)\subseteq G$.  Can you use that to show that $H$ contains an interval around $xy$?

Comment: Bonus question for the OP: If we drop the condition that $0\notin G$, does it change anything?

Answer (score 1):

For $y\ne 0$, the map $x\mapsto xy$ is a homeomorphism $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, hence with $G$ also $Gy$ is open. Then $H=\bigcup_{y\in G} Gy$ is the union of open sets, hence open.

---

Remarkably, the *result* does not change if we allow $0\in G$, though the *method* of proof above becomes problematic: If $0\in H$ then $0\in G$, then some $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subseteq G$, then $(-\epsilon^2,\epsilon^2)\subseteq H$, so $0$ is an inner point of $h$, For the rest consider $G\setminus\{0\}$ and the first paragraph.

Comment: I dont think a beginner can understand this solution.

Comment: @Lemur: Why not? The proof uses only definitions and elementary calculus.

Comment: I don't see any calculus here...

Comment: @Nishant Therer is none. It's really just the fact that the union of open sets is open, and - if one does not like the word homeomorphism - division by $y\ne0$ is continuous, hence $Gy$, being the inverse image of the open set $G$ under a continuous map, is open.